# LIKE clause in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have to search records where `cityname like '%United States;AK;Adak%'`
and on basis of result, store value of columns in my viewmodel objects.

I have written following code and it is causing an error when casting from a number value must be less than infinity.

```
zipcode=United States;AK;Adak;

var zipcd = (from u in db.ZipCodes1
             where u.CityName.Contains(zipcode) && u.CityType == "D"
             select u).ToList().Select(u => new Viewsearch
             {
                 Zipcode = u.ZIPCode,
                 CityName = u.CityName,
                 stateabbr = u.StateAbbr
             }).Distinct();

Viewsearch vs = (Viewsearch)zipcd;

if (zipcd.Count() > 1)
{
    locations = "United States;" + vs.stateabbr + ";" + vs.CityName;
}
else if (locations == "") 
{
    locations = "United States;" + vs.stateabbr + ";" + vs.CityName;
}
else
{
    locations = "United States;" + vs.stateabbr + ";" + vs.CityName + "," + locations;
}

if (zipcd.Count() > 3)
{
    locations = locations.Replace(locations, "," + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit - That is a different error message to earlier? Never mind

Your cast is wrong - you're trying to cast the results of the query (possibly more than 1 result) to a single object.

```
Viewsearch vs = (Viewsearch)zipcd;
```

Your `zipcd` is an `IQueryable<Viewsearch>`, not a `Viewsearch`. You could use `Single()` or `First()` if you're expecting only 1 result or want to use the first result respectively, or you need to write code based on there being an IEnumerable/IQueryable of objects returned.

Comment: zipcode is of char type,cityname is of varchar type and citytype is of char type and in model all objects are of string type give me solution and full error msg is Unable to cast object of type '<DistinctIterator>d__81`1[ITClassifieds.Models.Viewsearch]' to type 'ITClassifieds.Models.Viewsearch'.

Comment: See edit - try to give full exception details though - the original question mentions "error when casting from a number value" - no resemblance to the one in your later comment!